# Supplying a deleter to a unique_ptr

Tags: c++, smart-pointers, unique-ptr

In the fifth edition of C++ Primer 5th Edition(p. 470):

> `unique_ptr<T, D> u(d)`  :   Null `unique_ptr` that points to objects of type `T` that uses `d`, which must be an object of type `D` in place of `delete`.

However, when I tried to supply the deleter function without a pointer object, the compiler(Visual Studio 2015) complains( no instance of constructor matches the argument list.). If I give the `unique_ptr` a pointer along with the deleter, it works fine.
So, am I misinterpreting something or is the book just wrong? If the book is wrong, is there any other way I can seperately supply a pointer and deleter to a `unique_ptr`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The constructor you are trying to call doesn't exist. According to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee410601.aspx#unique_ptr__unique_ptr), the only constructors that take a deleter function take a pointer as well. If you want to initialize a `unique_ptr` with a deleter but don't want to give it a value yet, you could always pass `nullptr` as the first parameter and call [`unique_ptr::reset()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee410601.aspx#unique_ptr__reset) to give it a pointer to manage later.